# What combination of stable GE isotopes make up the germanium in a Ge(Li) spectrometer

Tags: nuclear-physics, atomic-physics, spectroscopy, isotopes

I work with a Ge(Li) gamma spectrometer. I'm trying to work out the different populations of stable Germanium isotopes in it. I'm trying to model the unrealistic scenario where none of these isotopes have become neutron activated, and they exist as they did when the detector was created.

My question is whether I can assume that the ratios of the different stable Ge isotopes in the detector correspond directly (approximately) to the percentage natural abundancies of Ge isotopes (IE 20% 70Ge, 27% 72Ge etc) or whether it's going to be more complicated than that.

Edit:

Another question had popped into my head. If I have a Ge(Li) detector, will the ammount of (for example) 72Ge at t=0 already be such that the change in it's population due to decays of other isotopes/neutron activation of Ge-72 will be largely irrelevant?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that a more important effect of using semicondctor detectors (Ge(Li), HPG, Si(Li) and others) in a neutron-ridden environment is the dislocation damage of the crystalline structure due to neutron irradiation.

Dislocations in the crystal increase the charge carrier collection time and decrease the efficiency of charge collection.  This results in a degradation of the energy resolution of the detector.

The whole reason one uses Ge(Li)s and HPGs is energy resolution.

Answer (score 1):

Unless it's been isotopically enriched on purpose, it's safe to assume natural abunances.  If you need better information, the best way to measure the ratios is with the gamma spectrum from thermal neutron activation, which it sounds like you're going to get for free.

Depending on your lithium doping you may care about $\rm ^7Li(n,2n){}^6Li$.