# Modelling populations of GE isotopes

Tags: nuclear-physics, atomic-physics, spectroscopy, isotopes

I asked a question similar to this here:

[What combination of stable GE isotopes make up the germanium in a Ge(Li) spectrometer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/209004/what-combination-of-stable-ge-isotopes-make-up-the-germanium-in-a-geli-spectro)

And got some very good answers. This question is instead based on the fact that I'm not using computer software to generate models and am trying to work out a couple myself (an intellectual exercise, my boss says!)

Specifically: I'm trying to work out, given a specific ammount of say, 70Ge, in a detector, how much becomes neutron activated to 71Ge, and how much 71Ge I have after time t. I've put together a model (it gets increasingly complicated) but it needs information such as Neutron flux into the Ge70 source, and the cross sections of Ge70/Ge71. This isn't information that I can get, is it?

If that information is unknown, how does the current software available model such things?

Comment: [Thermal cross sections](http://www.nndc.bnl.gov/atlas/atlasvalues.html), maintained by Mughabghab; for energy dependence search the [evaluated nuclear data files](http://www.nndc.bnl.gov/exfor/endf00.jsp), which is the data used by e.g. MCNP.

Comment: I note that you've been using Phys.SE very heavily for this project.

Comment: It seems unlikely that we could tell you the neutron flux in your experiments... But @rob (continues) to be right - the cross sections are pretty standard, known, tabulated data. Then it is 'just' a matter of writing down some equations and solving them.

Comment: I'm less using it to get work done, more to understand better/get a better depth of understanding. I am also a Maths undergrad, so I sometimes lack fundamental understanding of some physics concepts or doubt myself. Also - Not one specific project at all. Various different work/studying around my field of work!